# Access Forbidden for Apache to a Windows Server 2012 NFS share

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, nfs, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows 2012 Server with an NFS share that is mounted on a Debian webserver running Apache. Apache is attempting to serve files from the the share but is getting a 403 access forbidden error.

The NFS share used to be on a Linux box with no issues. Windows permissions are setup so "Everyone" has RW access. The files are visible from the local Linux server so I think it's a user mapping problem with Apache.

Has anyone dealt with this before?

Comment: Share permissions are not the same as the folder's ACL permissions - check that Everyone has permissions on the actual folder as well.

Comment: "Everyone" does have read/write

Comment: What is the error log showing? And if you do an ls -la of the directory where you mounted the NFS share, are the permissions shown correct?

Comment: Permissions are rwx for everyone in Linux as well as in Windows. I haven't found any relevant errors in any logs since it's only a 403